# Unable to create spark-warehouse directory using spark-2.3.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, akka

I want to create a project with akka and spark. I added dependencies and some other dependencies too. Is these dependencies will cause any effect on using spark.

I have below sbt file

```
    dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7"
    dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7"
    dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.8.7"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.bitool.analytics",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.12",
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-async" % "0.9.6",
    "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "macros" % "2.3.0",
    "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "macrosakka" % "2.3.0",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.6",
    "io.swagger" % "swagger-jaxrs" % "1.5.19",
    "com.github.swagger-akka-http" %% "swagger-akka-http" % "0.9.1",
    "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.8.0", 
    "io.circe" %% "circe-literal" % "0.8.0", 
    "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % "0.8.0", 
    "io.circe" %% "circe-optics" % "0.8.0", 
    "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "8.0.144-R12",
    "org.scalafx" %% "scalafxml-core-sfx8" % "0.4",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.3.0",
    "org.scala-lang" % "scala-xml" % "2.11.0-M4",
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.5"
  )
)
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "BITOOL-1.0"
  )
ivyScala := ivyScala.value map {
  _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true)
}
fork in run := true
```

and below is my spark code

```
private val warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath
val conf = new SparkConf()
  conf.setMaster("local[4]")
  conf.setAppName("Bitool")
  conf.set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)

  val SPARK = SparkSession
    .builder().config(conf).enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
  val SPARK_CONTEXT = SPARK.sparkContext
```

When I trying to execute this, It is creating metastore_db folder but spark-warehouse folder is not creating.

Comment: what happens when you remove the `conf.set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)`? Normally, my directory is created in the project directory because I am using `sbt run` there.

Comment: I tried it by removing warehouselocation . It is not creating spark-warehouse folder.

Comment: does the directory get created when you remove `enableHiveSupport`? what happens if you create the directory manually (permission issue)? I think hive uses `hdfs` path, or the hive metastore. Also try adding `file:///` before your `warehouseLocation` path.

Comment: I am getting below error when I tried with enableHiveSupport

373574 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] WARN hive.ql.metadata.Hive  - Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Answer (score 0):

This directory is not created by `getOrCreate`. You can check it in the Spark source code: `getOrCreate` delegates its actions to `SparkSession.getOrCreate`, which is just a setter. All the internal tests and `CliSuite` use a snippet like this to prematurely initialize the dir: `val warehousePath = Utils.createTempDir()`

Instead, in the actual user code, you have to perform at least one data modification operation to materialize your warehouse directory. Try running something like that just after your code and check warehouse directory on the hard drive again:

```scala
  import SPARK.implicits._
  import SPARK.sql
  sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test")
  sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (key INT, value STRING) USING hive")
```